# Running rpy2 gives me the error LookupError: tzone

Tags: python, rpy2

I try to import some R library in python through rpy2 (rpy2>=3.0). However i get the error below. Using python 2 and rpy2==2.80 this works. As well as using python 3 and rpy2==2.9.1.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testMultipipsa.py", line 70, in <module>
    pr.runClusterPipsa(ingrp+outgrp,points=[],cluster=cl0)
  File "multipipsa-4.0.2/multipipsa/multipipsa.py", line 625, in runClusterPipsa
    self.runPipsa(structures, points=points)
  File "multipipsa-4.0.2/multipipsa/multipipsa.py", line 674, in runPipsa
    pipsaLog="sims"+filesuffix+".log")
  File "multipipsa-4.0.2/multipipsa/clusterpipsa.py", line 113, in clusterSingleRun
    base = rpackages.importr('base')
  File "site-packages/rpy2-3.0.0-py3.7.egg/rpy2/robjects/packages.py", line 492, in importr
  File "site-packages/rpy2-3.0.0-py3.7.egg/rpy2/robjects/packages.py", line 204, in __init__
  File "site-packages/rpy2-3.0.0-py3.7.egg/rpy2/robjects/packages.py", line 330, in __fill_rpy2r__
  File "site-packages/rpy2-3.0.0-py3.7.egg/rpy2/robjects/packages.py", line 264, in __fill_rpy2r__
  File "functools.py", line 827, in wrapper
    return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
  File "site-packages/rpy2-3.0.0-py3.7.egg/rpy2/robjects/pandas2ri.py", line 177, in rpy2py_floatvector
  File "site-packages/rpy2-3.0.0-py3.7.egg/rpy2/rinterface_lib/conversion.py", line 28, in _
  File "site-packages/rpy2-3.0.0-py3.7.egg/rpy2/rinterface_lib/sexp.py", line 148, in do_slot
LookupError: tzone
```

Comment: Sorry, you need to provide more information. As such, your question cannot really be treated.

Comment: If you want us to suggest where the problem is in the code, we need to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug introduced in a recent update of `rpy2`, and is reported in [this thread](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/533/running-rpy2-gives-me-the-error#comment-51644619). You can find there comments and workaround suggestions, still work-in-progress as of today.

Alternatively, a quick fix is to revert to an older version, for example with `pip` you could enter:

```
pip install rpy2==2.9.5
```